# Sound files not included while Building JAR files in netbeans and Source deleted too

Tags: java, jar

I created a miniTennis program,with Sounds files included in it. But when I am trying to build it from NetBeans (Creating jar file) , those sound files are automatically deleted from my classes folder and also they are not included in `.jar` file.

I have no idea ,what's the problem?

Comment: Could you edit the question and add more details? For example folder structure, how you compile,...

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the usual (my `src/` folder only should contain java sources) rule in your ant file.

Create a `resources` folder and mark it respectively. It should then be picked up when building a jar file.